# Jenkins with Gerrit - Triggering a CI job on a multi-repo project, configure trigger for multiple commits that have the same subject

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit, repo

I am working on a project that is configured within multiple git repositories and managed by a manifest.xml with the repo tool.

On a daily basis, changes for each git repo are submitted on Gerrit and currently attempting to implement the gerrit trigger with Jenkins to execute a job. That part is indeed working.

The issue comes when some changes relate to 2 or more different git repos (having the same ID/subject of change on the commit message). As currently every-single git repo is monitored and a job is triggered upon a commit.

How will it be possible to prevent the individual trigger if there are 2 or more commits to be made and necessary to be built together? And trigger the build only once all the relevant commits are available on gerrit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the field "Add TOPIC" in "Dynamic Trigger Configuration" which could be set across gits.